# Python selenium don't autoplay videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the Selenium webdriver in Python and I'd like the browser to not load images or autoplay videos to save time and resources. The problem is that videos do still get played without clicking on them.

Here are my settings for the webbrowser:

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

# don't load images
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('extensions.contentblocker.enabled', True)
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', False)

# no video autoplay
firefox_profile.set_preference('media.autoplay.default', 1)
firefox_profile.set_preference('media.autoplay.allow-muted', False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
```

How can I stop the browser from autoplaying videos?

Comment: Can you provide a website where this is happening? I used your code on a YouTube live video and it didn't auto-played -  `driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC00XLKpLgkJhN3L1QBtdz1A/live")`

Comment: On Twitter the videos are still loading. Maybe that's not preventable.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the videos from loading or auto-playing?

Comment: Both would be okay. I'm just trying to save some time & bandwidth.

Comment: You can create a JavaScript loop that sets the source of all video elements to an empty string on pageload